# Setting timer in Python

Tags: python, timer

Hey guys I'm doing a program in python. It's a calculation program which gives you two random number from 2 to 10, and then asks you for example how much is 2 * 4.

And if your answer is correct it gives you a point. Now, I want that the program let's the user calculate for 20secs and when 20secs are over, it will show you how much points you have.

My code so far ->

```
__author__ = 'Majky'
import random
import time

a = random.randint(2, 10)
b = random.randint(2, 10)
print("How much is", a, "times", b)
t = 0

odg = int(input("Answer ?"))
sec = 0

while sec < 20:

if odg == a * b:
print("Correct")
t = +1
print("Incorrect")

print("Your points are", t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to want to use [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), and open a parallel thread that will calculate that time (maybe by using time.sleep()) and return once done, once it returns, the main thread will stop execution and return the results. 
Using sleep() in the main program will just pause execution for that time, which is not what you want from what I understand. You want the user to be able to interact with the program while the timer is running. That is what using threads from the threading module will allow you to do.

Here is a quick example of the use of threading (adjust it if you need anything specific):

```python
import random
import time

def main():
  thread_stop = threading.Event()
  thread = threading.Thread(target=user_thread,  args=(2, thread_stop))

  time.sleep(20)

  thread_stop.set()


def user_thread(arg1, stop_event):
  t = 0
  while(not stop_event.is_set()):
      a = random.randint(2, 10)
      b = random.randint(2, 10)
      print("How much is", a, "times", b)

      odg = int(input("Answer ?"))

      if odg == a * b:
        print("Correct")
        t += 1
      else:
        print("Incorrect")

  print("Your points are", t)

main()
```

Here is also an example using signals that stops the user in the middle of an answer if the 20 seconds are up and counts the results. This example uses signals, which is in itself an interesting module to control execution flow, you should check its documentation when you get a chance. 
I also realized there was another error in your code which I overlooked and has been corrected now in both examples, when you want to increase "t", use "t+=1", since "t=+1" is incorrect, the last expression is just assigning "positive" one to t every time, so is not increased. Cheers!

```python
import signal

t = 0
#Here we register a handler for timeout
def handler(signum, frame):
  #print "Time is up!"
  raise Exception("Time is up.")

#function to execute your logic where questions are asked
def looped_questions():
  import random
  global t
  while 1:
    #Here is the logic for the questions
    a = random.randint(2, 10)
    b = random.randint(2, 10)
    print("How much is", a, "times", b)
    odg = int(input("Answer ?"))
    if odg == a * b:
      t += 1
      print("Correct")
    else:
      print("Incorrect")

#Register the signal handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)

#Set the timeout
signal.alarm(20)

try:
  looped_questions()
except Exception, exc:
  print exc
  #Here goes the results logic
  print("Your points are", t)
```

Also, don't forget to add to that sanity checks so that invalid user input doesn't break your code. I will leave that to you ;)

Comment: okay i am reading this but if I am honest i have no idea where to put something now..

Comment: Here is an example of what the thread structure will look like, just introduce your logic in the placeholders I gave you:
`code:
import random
import time

def main():
  thread_stop = threading.Event()
  thread = threading.Thread(target=user_thread,  args=(2, thread_stop))

  time.sleep(20)
  
  thread_stop.set()
  #Results processing and displaying logic goes here.

def user_thread(arg1, stop_event):
  while(not stop_event.is_set()):
      #Logic for interacting with user and storing the user's answers goes here.


main()
`
I will post it in the answer...

Comment: You got a code example now of the whole thing. Adjust as needed.

Comment: Thank you. One more thing if I may... When 20 seconds are past i don't want the last answer to be counted as correct. Do you get what I mean ? the user is answering and when 20 secs are over, if he answers correctly to the question after 20 seconds, that answer doesn't count

Comment: See the example I posted, it uses signals to have the exact behavior you want. Is a tested example, and I also fixed something that was wrong with the count, see my notes. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `time.sleep(20)` function to wait 20 seconds.

This function suspend execution for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time.

The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the `sleep()` following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this, using `time.time()`.

```
import time
...
start = time.time()
answer = raw_input('enter solution')
finish = time.time()
if finish - start > 20:
    #failure condition
else:
    #success condition
```